# cellforrowatindexpath mixing up data in cells

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

My cells are getting data mixed up in cellforrowatindexpath. I change the text color and text of a label, but even though the isComplete value changes , the cell color and text changes randomly.

For example as I scroll through the table view, complete tasks are sometimes red.  What is strange is that this only happens to the cells I scroll to, and not the cells that load initially and are visible on the screen.

Here is what my method looks like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TaskCell *cell = [tableView
                             dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TaskCell"];
    PFObject *player = (_tasks)[indexPath.row];

    NSString *taskType =  player[@"name"];
    NSNumber *completeNum = player[@"complete"];
    BOOL isComplete = [completeNum boolValue];


    UIImage *completeImage;
    NSLog(@"task: %@ is complete %@", player[@"taskDescription"], player[@"complete"]);
    if(isComplete){
       completeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check"];
       cell.taskDescriptionLabel.text = player[@"taskDescription"];
    }else{
       completeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"x2"];
        cell.taskDescriptionLabel.text = @"Incomplete";
        cell.taskDescriptionLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    cell.taskCompletedImage.image = completeImage;


    cell.TaskTypeLabel.text = taskType;

    return cell;
}
```

why is this happening?

Comment: Code looks okay to me.  Referring to the array (_tasks) is a little strange.  Is that a property?  How about self.tasks?  Also, why would you call an element in the tasks array a "player"?  But none of that explains the problem.

Comment: Your issue actually lies within how you're setting the `player[@"complete"]` property. Please supply the code of how you're setting that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the cell is reused you would have red color as you are using an reused instance of a cell which has red color. Reset the color by overriding prepareForReuse method. Or reset the color every time the cell is configured as below.

```
if(isComplete){
   completeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check"];
   cell.taskDescriptionLabel.text = player[@"taskDescription"];
   cell.taskDescriptionLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}else{
   completeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"x2"];
    cell.taskDescriptionLabel.text = @"Incomplete";
    cell.taskDescriptionLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```